# How to beautify Powershell/command prompt responses into a proper JSON without any backslashes or newline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, powershell

I've tried to parse it even before with the commands like Get-ComputerInfo | ConvertTo-Json , systeminfo | ConvertTo-Json. The responses are in a proper json format when it comes in powershell/cmd. The problem is, when we are trying to pass that data into an api, it has many unwanted /r/n and "/ /". How we could beautify that in a json format?

I've used many regex formats to remove /r /n from the string. And it works. But still there are many slashes inside the responses. Apart from these newline and backslashes, taking a specific data from a powershell response, it is very difficult to pick a data if it is a string data with unwanted slashes instead of parsed data like object or array.

Comment: Can you add a code sample that shows exactly what you're doing (your current sample has a syntax error "Missing argument in parameter list." and it's unclear what the correction should be). Can you also add an example of the desired output. Note if you're pipeing the output from ```ConvertTo-Json``` into a second call to ```ConvertTo-Json``` that would give the escaped line ending characters you're seeing, but it's hard tell what the fix is without a runnable code sample and the desired output.

Comment: Maybe `Get-ComputerInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`?

Comment: @mclayton most likely has the right of it with the double `ConvertTo-Json` calls but you may also be getting additional line ending information if you are not encoding the files correctly when you export them. Json expects UTF8, so however you are writing your file(s), encode them correctly `Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath C:\Path\Filename`